# Unity take high resolution screenshot with webcamtexture on ios

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, camera

I would like to take a picture from my back camera on my ios.
I am using webcamtexture to get the back camera status.
I print those pixels on a UI Texture, after that I capture a screenshot.

Everything works fine, but the quality is pixelated because the webcamtexture has a maximum of 1920x1080 resolution.
Is there any other way to get a picture from a device camera in unity?

I already tried a lot of plugins but none of them seem to work better.

Comment: 1920x1080 res from a mobile device is pixelated to you?

Comment: Maybe not pixelated but there is a lot noise in the picture